# Iterate through List from Controller to View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Ok. so I have this controller that retrieves the user password.

```
 Function ViewUsers(ByVal users As Users) As ViewResult

        Dim pwordList = New List(Of String)()
        Dim passdecList = New List(Of String)()
        Dim pwordQuery = From pword In db.UsersDB
                         Select pword.Password


        For Each pass As String In pwordList

            passString = PassEncrypt.Decrypt(pass)

            passdecList.Add(passString)
           //send each decrypted password to a table Password column in the view
        Next

    End Function
```

I dont know how I would do it.

Comment: Don't store passwords in reversible form, and **never** (_never!_) display them to admins.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be storing passwords in clear text in your database. They should always be encrypted. But for the purpose of this example you could do the following:

```
Function ViewUsers(ByVal users As Users) As ViewResult
    Dim pwordList = db.UsersDB.Select(Function(u)u.Password).ToList()
    return View(pwordList)
End Function
```

and inside your strongly typed view:

```
@ModelType List(Of string)
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Password</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @For Each password In Model
            @<tr><td>@item</td></tr>
        Next password
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: He is encrypting them (see `PassEncrypt.Decrypt`).  They should always be **hashed**.

Comment: Yes, I created a function to encrypt and decrypt passwords. So the encrypted passwords are in my db. as you can see in my controller, i used linq to select the passwords from db and encrypted each one and added those to a list. In my view, I created a for each loop to iterate thru the database but putting in the for each loop for the password inside of the other for each would cause redundancy of rows.